# Como colocar o titulo da página HTML de acordo com o nome do usuário no banco de dados?

Tags: php, html, login

Olá, estou criando um sistema de cadastro e login, e quero que quando o usuário terminar de fazer seu cadastro e logar a primeira vez, o titulo da página do site fique com o nome dele.

Tipo assim:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
 <title> <?php echo $nomedapessoa; ?> </title>
 </head>
 <body>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Porém não estou conseguindo fazer essa comunicação com o banco de dados. Preciso de uma ajuda de vocês.

Obs: Utilizo PHP.

Comment: Poste a parte do banco de dados, fica mais facil ajudar.

Comment: Só um detalhe, porque editando vi editando a pergunta que vc fala em página HTML:  para o servidor ler a variável, a página tem que ser `.php`.

Answer (score 2):

Ao efetuar o login em php, registre o nome do seu usuário na SESSION.
Feito o login em php, faça:

```
<?php
       session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
     <head>
          <title> <?php echo $_SESSION['nomedapessoa']; ?> </title>
     </head>
     <body>
     </body>
 </html>
```